# Suggest: Difficulty Vote Feature

Tags: feature-request

I just came across this question in Meta: [SO fails to promote well-researched, well-written, but difficult questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396963/so-fails-to-promote-well-researched-well-written-but-difficult-questions?cb=1#), and once I finished reading it. I think of something I might bring some discussions about a feature that can somehow approaches the problem.

The problem is that questions currently have no indicator that shows how **difficult** the questions are. Challenging and time-consuming questions will just award with the **same amount** of *fake internet points* as easy questions that someone just come by and answer it within a few seconds. One would just keep answering easy questions rather than spending hours to try to solve a question that will yield the same reward.

I think if there is a feature that indicates the **difficulty** of a question and such feature is able to affect the reputation gain from answering its question then it might be some progress for us. I would call it a **Difficulty Vote** (DV) or it can be named anything, really, only the feature functionality that I care about.

**What is the definition of a difficult question?**

If a Gold Badge user cannot answer a question, it is considered
"difficult" and hence worth a DV.

**How it works and its conditions are as the following:**

1. Only a **Gold Badge** user of one of the question's tags is able to upvote the DV. Therefore, only experts can vote that this question is difficult. (I am also thinking that if a Gold Badge user upvotes the DV, the user is no longer able to answer the question)
2. DV will affect the reputation gain by some conditions that it is really on SO to decide. For example, if the question has more than 5 DVs then the accepted answer will get +50 more reputations from what a normal accepted answer would get. Bounty is still able to further push the reward.

**What benefits will this feature bring to SO site and its community?**

1. Questions will have more information about how difficult they are.
2. Difficult questions are encouraging users to answer by their attractive reward (extra reputations).
3. Can be another dimension to analyze in terms of statistics data.

Let's discuss!

**Updated "difficulty" definition.**

Comment: What if there's a new tag, or tags without gold badgers? What possible ways you can see your feature request being abused? Why can't we use existing methods (bounties) to draw attention to such questions?

Comment: @SamuelLiew 1. Gold Badgers, to me, are guaranteed experts in SO. If there is another way to identify them then feel free to suggest. Therefore, if a tag has no gold badgers then no one will be able to use the feature in such tag.

Comment: @SamuelLiew 2. One possible way is that a gold badger upvotes DV to trigger another ceiling of reward and then answer the question by himself, so I put my opinion in the #1 of how it works to rule out this possibility. Another one is that people are going to wait for another ceiling to trigger by some gold badgers for more reward and then answer it when the reward is high enough, which is exactly what it is really intended for because they wouldn't bother solving this question any way if they don't want to.

Comment: As if we don't have enough "I searched Netflix for two weeks and could not find an answer but you just downcasted my perfect question"... Now twice as much - one for downvotes, one for "you are complete ... elitist - this is very difficult question. And I'm not going even try to investigate myself as it is so difficult one".

Comment: Why do or should we care about the difficulty level of a question? Regardless of difficulty level, good questions and answers make a contribution to our knowledge base, which is the mission of this site.

Comment: "Difficulty" is highly subjective. It doesn't depend on the question alone, but also on the experience level of individual users.

Comment: @ModusTollens So I scope the usage to only the Experts in the field (Gold Badge users). If experts say it is difficult, it "most likely" is really difficult.

Comment: Until you define "difficulty of a question" this doesn't say anything.

Comment: @philipxy If a Gold Badge user cannot answer a question, it is considered "difficult" and hence worth a DV.

Comment: @CodyGray There are several unanswered questions that have not been attractive enough or are difficult that made them still unanswered. This will make that kind of questions from this moment onward to be more attractive so that they will get answers. Since more questions get answered, shouldn't we, the community, care about it that it helps contributing to our knowledge base further more or less.

Comment: Your post doesn't say that.

Comment: @philipxy I'm so sorry. I will update the information accordingly.

Comment: Your comment describes precisely what the bounty system is intended to resolve.

Comment: General purpose programming languages can be used for a _very_ broad field of problems.  Gold badge holders for a given language tags are not likely to be experts in every problem area however. E.g. I am a Python gold badge holder but you won’t find me answering machine learning questions, but not every Python machine learning question is “difficult”. On the other hand, I find Flask questions (a Python web framework), easy. Will all the Python machine learning experts have voted those questions as “difficult”?

Comment: @MartijnPieters It depends on individual expert. If one is not expert in the field, you should give no vote. If you consider yourself one and you think it is difficult or you cannot answer it then you should upvate DV so it makes sense.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I feel you made my point better than me. And before me. Just as another example - let's say I've a gold badge in a language. If there is a question that is algorithmic in nature, like "Find 3D area encompassed by some object" I wouldn't be able to answer it because I not that good with geometry. Yet that doesn't mean the question is hard because of the language. A user completely unfamiliar with the language could answer it had they the mathematical knowledge. So, what's "difficult" for a gold badge holder doesn't mean it's "difficult" overall.

Comment: @holydragon that’s not what will happen. Your feature gives this power to *all* gold badge holders in a tag. Users will not arbitrarily hold back using it. The bounty system already covers the same use cases and at least incurs a cost for the “difficulty vote” (placing a bounty requires investing your rep), and that cost regulates their use. How would you regulate “difficulty votes”?

Comment: *Gold Badge user cannot answer a question, it is considered "difficult" and hence worth a DV.* --> I have a gold badge on the JS tag and I don't answer JS questions .. I simply got it because many CSS question are tagged with JS so I am far from being a JS expert

Comment: I now realize that Gold Badge user is not a guaranteed expert of the field. However, my point is that I want bind the ability to DV with experts but there is no way to identify the experts of the field for each question in SO. So, this is not going to work. Thank you.

Comment: "There are two hard things in computer science: cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-one errors." -- [Jeff Atwood](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/506010907021828096). Nearly all questions asked on the site are fundamentally easy and come down to help using a language feature or hitting a typical gotcha. SO isn't typically a platform for solving difficult research problems on the frontiers of computer science. And even if we were facing truly difficult problems, there's no obvious benefit in voting or bucketing them differently, and even if there was, nobody will agree on how.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that "DV" typically means "downvote", which adds a lot of cognitive difficulty in reading this proposal. "if a Gold Badge user upvotes the DV" reads like "if a Gold Badge user upvotes the downvote".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To briefly go through the stated benefits:

> 1. Questions will have more information about how difficult they are.

I don't know that this information is even quantifiable. What is difficult for one person might be very simple for someone else - even Gold Badge users don't know everything about the tag they hold a badge in, especially if the tag is very broad/popular.

> 2. Difficult questions are encouraging users to answer by their attractive reward (extra reputations).

We already have attractive rewards for answering questions - reputation and bounties. If someone thinks their question is deserving of more attention, that's what the bounty system is there for.

> 3. Can be another dimension to analyze in terms of statistics data.

I don't know much about statistics so can't be objective here, but I don't see much value in tracking "difficult" questions.

Tl;dr: "Difficulty" is largely subjective. What one Gold Badge user might find particularly challenging, another might think very simple. I don't think this is a good idea.

Comment: "*If someone thinks their question is deserving of more attention, that's what the bounty system is there for.*" worth noting that people can place bounties on somebody else's questions as well. So, in a sense an expert can already reward "difficult question" by putting a bounty on it.