# Is the feedback provided by downvotes to the "question asker" just noise to the "asker"?

Tags: discussion, downvote-reason

It is already decided by the [community](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357437/) that

- Downvotes are, first and foremost, a content rating system. Rather than being a way of communicating with the poster, they are a way of communicating to future readers that a question or answer is not interesting or useful.

Following the agreed upon interpretation, downvotes are just noise to the asker as they show nothing other than "What the community thinks is different from what you think about the quality of your post".  This feedback is mostly useless to the asker as it doesn't show  what is wrong except that something may be wrong.

Should this feedback be shown to the question asker at all? Could we weigh the pros and cons of showing this metric to the asker?  Is this feedback that valuable or valuable at all to the "asker" that showing it to them is warranted against all the backlash received so far? Or *Is it because people here are curmudgeonly trolls who just hate people and don't want new users to feel welcome?*

Comment: Disclosure: This is a discussion post asking for the community opinion on the **worth** of showing a metric to a individual following a [failed feature request proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400284).

Comment: If there was some way to display the current close votes description to the question asker (even before the question is closed), that would be more useful than the (negative) post score.

Comment: @charlietfl A downvote  obviously doesn't even show that: Does it  show a lack of research effort? OR  is it unclear? OR Is it unanswerable?  Furthermore, these are close vote reasons. Questions quickly close voted would show these to the OP. I'm of the opinion that any research or modifications should be done before and not after. Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396963 This solves a part of this problem.

Comment: There's nothing specific to downvotes in this reasoning. Would you also propose not showing upvotes?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica As a matter of fact **Yes** as it is still useless to the  "asker" and is just "noise" from "asker's point of view". FWIW, this is not a proposal, but a discussion.

Comment: Votes are a content rating mechanism for the community and as a part of the community the OP deserves to see it. It feels like this was discussed very recently, I'm sure you saw that discussion.

Comment: Is there really any need for that trailing, loaded question?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Not sure what you mean, but if you meant the last line, it's a direct reference to [this question's last line](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436/8). It is needed because that's how the  general new user community views SO. And if you're going to differentiate the "poster" from the "community" by saying `Rather than being a way of communicating with the poster`, It should be done fully for the reason to be valid. In any case, this is not a moral issue or who deserves what. It's purely a pro vs cons of **value** of downvote to a asker from a productivity/efficiency standpoint

Comment: somewhat related at other meta: [Downvoting off-topic MSE posts is counterproductive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317379/165773) "If I was an inexperienced asker and if I had my question deleted at small negative score I would think that possibly I just accidentally caught an eye of some overly strict moderator and maybe it makes sense to try my luck and ask again... Things would probably be different if there was efficient guidance about question quality and topicality or safety roadblocks for confused askers. But in the absence of these downvotes could do the job about as well."

Comment: @gnat Given that the post is almost 2 years old and nothing seems to have been done, Is downvotes really just masking the problem? A shortcut is good, but obviously has serious side effects:  Backlash from new users, Rages from downvotes, Publicized highly unwelcome nature of SO.  Maybe it's time to put down the power of  the shortcut so that real effective actions with less side effects can be taken. We can't keep relying on downvotes.

Comment: I consider downvotes a viable long term solution. Downsides you mention are for real but I believe these are outweight by the benefits - specifically, this way doesn't depend on company desire to invest dev effort into improving askers experience, nor on whether such effort would succeed or fail. In other words it lets us maintain site quality by ourselves. In the (rather unlikely) case that company decides to put effort in that and succeeds we will probably see downvotes naturally fading (because folks won't spend time on things that will be done right by the system without them)

Comment: Downvotes are not effective: very very few users actually improve their question and don't work as punishment (as most users are first-time users and don't know about downvotes until after the fact). Downvotes are unnecessary inflicted pain if the question is going to be deleted anyway. Downvotes are also unnecessary public shaming (it would be better to wait (with an opt-out option) with publication until the question is in an acceptable state). There must be a way to get the desired effects without the drawbacks of downvotes.

Comment: @PeterMortensen The score of the post says what other people thought of it. It's effective at sending that signal. I don't understand about the "public shaming". If someone posts something others don't like, how is the content not shaming in itself? It least when the score it low, less people are likely to see it.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Sometimes, yes; a problem is posed, code presented, along attempted resolutions - and still a downvote. Then editing "Why the downvotes?", and a desert echo.

The quoted "definition" of downvotes is meaningless; users don't sit around a table and jointly agree "Yes, this is, indeed, what we shall mean by 'downvote'". It  varies by the user - and those on the receiving end of (perceived) unwarranted and unexplained downvotes form a negative assosciation, potentially [discouraging](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398537/10133797) them from downvoting.

A remedy, one that'd at least encourage me to downvote more, would be a menu of explanations followed by "submit" (downvote), just as in review queues/close votes. I often see questions with clear problems, but *don't* downvote as I rather not invest time crafting up a sentence.

---

**Update**: anonymous feedback was suggested in comments; I agree. The *option* would help; then I can convey the same idea but not necessarily in same quality wording / sentence structure, thus reducing effort.

Further, it can be a combination of "predefined reasons" (unclear, etc) PLUS a custom comment; the comment can now be two words instead of a sentence. It may seem like "what's your beef with typing a sentence", but when you have to do it for many questions when you have no incentive to do so at all, it matters.

Comment: *A remedy, one that'd at least encourage me to downvote more, would be a menu of explanations followed by "submit" (downvote), just as in review queues/close votes.* Seems like  a great idea. A possible modification is to simply open up a menu of explanations after clicking the downvote(with no submit). A click can be reduced. This saves time in crafting up a sentence => also provides a relatively "specific" feedback to OP with anonymity.

Comment: Related post on meta SE: [Explaining downvotes, a new take on things](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353141/348196). I believe that a list of canned reasons (to prevent abuse) posted anonymously is a good idea. And maybe the list can be editable by moderators so that new reasons can be added easily.

Comment: Not gonna happen. Downvotes are the most straightforward way of saying *this post is not good*; forcing the downvoter to choose an over-generalized reason that barely explains their rationale for downvote is counter-productive for the content rating system. Explaining your rating **have to** be optional, otherwise there won't be enough input to judge content quality. Hence the downvote.

Comment: @oguzismail Optional explanations is agreeable. But I don't think OverLord meant compulsory. Would you agree with the related meta proposal https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353141 where it is explicitly mentioned that such feedback is optional?

Comment: @TheMaster we already have a feature for that, you can use comments to give feedback.

Comment: @oguzismail Comments are not anonymous. I just [posted a refined proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/353384/348196) in the question that I referred to above. The TL;DR is: 1) You have the option to downvote and move on. 2) You have the option to provide feedback anonymously using canned reasons. 3) Canned reasons are editable by mods. 4) You have the option to post a public feedback in a comment.

Comment: @4 Still counter-productive. The functionality provided by the downvote button must be preserved. If users want to give feedback anonymously -why that is necessary is what I don't understand-, there should be an extra button for that next to edit, close, etc.

Comment: @oguzismail As I mentioned in that answer, the dialog can either be dismissed by hitting `Esc` or be opened by clicking a button that appears after downvoting. I think the former option won't slow things down but we can go with the latter if that's what the community prefers. _"why that is necessary is what I don't understand"_ - Users tend to be reluctant to leave a comment after downvoting a post to avoid being a subject of revenge downvoting. I hear this concern very often.

Comment: Revenge downvoting if chained can be reversed, a couple downvotes doesn't hurt anybody. Besides if a user makes revenge downvoting a habit and causes trouble that can be detected and appropriate action would be taken by moderators. *Oh I'm scared of downvotes!* is not an argument. Wrt the dialog, my opinion is **no**, I don't want to hit Esc every time. What community prefers doesn't really make any difference here, such changes aren't decided democratically, and that's a good thing.

Comment: An anonymous way to give feedback (completely detached from the quality voting system): I'd very much welcome that. A cookie-cutter list of choices... no thank you. If you want to give feedback then it should not be lazy feedback; it should be tailored to the post and be as complete as possible.

Answer (score 18):

*No*, votes are valuable to question askers.

Votes are a collective rating by the community. They express the opinion of a silent majority, which does not comment for a variety of reasons.

In contrast, any *specific* explanation of question quality is inherently an individual rating. It is one person's opinion, and that may well be wrong.

It is the *combination* of votes and comments that should be the most useful to a question asker. At +5, there is no pressure to satisfy every pedantic comment. At -5, better listen to what people say.

---

Of course there are situations when there are only votes, not comments – after all, there is no requirement to comment. However, in this case votes are literally the only feedback to a poster that their content is lacking. Not letting a poster know in any way that their content is lacking seems much worse than providing only fuzzy feedback.

---

So *what if* votes were not shown?

Posters with positive score are not shown that they did a good job. Votes are the primary gamification of "posting well", and this would be removed. *Hiding votes would remove the main gratification of contributing good content.*

Posters with negative score *who can take it* are not shown that they should improve. Posters must actively check whether they need to take action. *Hiding votes would artificially delay posters from improving their content.*

Posters with negative score *who feel offended* are protected from the negative message. However, that negative message is not gone, it is just not shown. *Hiding votes means the negativity happens behind the poster's back.* (IMO that is bad, but it probably depends on the individual.)

---

Let us assume that protecting posters from negativity of downvoting would work. What does that mean *for voters*?

Honestly, *I would downvote more*.

When I *currently* see a -3, or -2, or sometimes even a -1 *that means the poster already got the message*. Not to be an evil prick, I try to give the poster their share of time to improve. Perhaps I follow the question and check in after some time. I try to only downvote if there is no sign of honest effort, if they are ignoring the message.

If there is no message to the poster, then it is just about the content. And the content which needs protecting the poster usually deserves to be downvoted.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220344/discussion-on-answer-by-mistermiyagi-is-the-feedback-provided-by-downvotes-to-th).

Comment: "It is one person's opinion" - and a downvote is what, exactly?

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Votes are the *sum of all voters*' opinions. Let me know if the wording in the answer needs clarifying.

Comment: A sum of _opinions_ is still a net-opinion, one that still carries minimal information to the asker. There are exceptions, but point is, _many_ downvotes aren't needed to sink a question - where 2 suffice, the asker better know what he's missing. (Exceptions apply; "obviously"/severely flawed questions aren't due explaining, but I refer to otherwise seemingly proper questions.)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to say *in the context of this answer*. Yes, votes are a sum of opinions, yes they still carry information. *That's the point* why they should not be hidden from authors, so that this information is accessible. I really don't see what the last sentence is supposed to say, both in relation to visibility and in general.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon After pondering that sentence, it seems to me like you are implying people should downvote less, or that they are too severely downvoting proper questions. Is my interpretation correct? How is that related to showing the votes?

Comment: "too severely downvoting proper questions" - to be closer, they downvote questions with no obvious flaws to (even a reasonable) asker. I've seen it several times - a question looks like many others in terms of "objective" traits like detail, code presented, attempted resolutions, yet the "others" are well-received while that question's sunk (and once sunk, much harder to unsink). _Those_ sorts of downvotes could use an explanation - definitely not saying "mandate"; again, it'll be _optional_, so there's really nothing to lose.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon I just have to mention here: I've seen questions neatly presented with headers and code and errors and get upvoted just for their presentation whereas OP knew not even the basic things about the language. Then I've seen well researched questions get closed or downvoted, because they got no code(in this case, no code is even needed) or others didn't understand the question(because they were unfamiliar with the concepts). Votes are superficial. Comments are relatively not, as they expose what a voter thinks and level of his skill.

Comment: I don’t see how the last two comments are relevant for this answer, or even for this question. Especially when it is just anecdotal. I recommend to prepare a SEDE query if you feel these are significant. Note also that one can already optionally explain downvoting via comments.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi they are related in the sense that the same sentiment: downvotes bad, community EVIL AND MEAN' guides it. It's just a new twist on 'Stack is mean, be less mean'.

Comment: @TheMaster I've added some pro/con (actually, mostly con since there wasn't much pro left after thinking it through). Is that what you are looking for? Let me know if you feel I missed some important case.

Comment: Partly yes. Having read arguments from yourself and others about the value of votes to a asker, it is mostly subjective and anecdotal. If I filter it down in terms of productivity to the site, **Downvotes improve the content by providing nonspecific negative feedback, thereby forcing the asker to improve the content**.  Like you said, A SEDE query showing the number of posts downvoted initially and that actually improve and get upvotes and that number being significant enough would go a long way in maintaining objectivity and would objectively solidify "the value of a downvote to the asker".

Answer (score 3):

**Votes on your own questions are valuable feedback.** It can tell you, just as it would anyone else, how well-received your post was. If the question you asked has a negative score, it should be a sign to you that you need to improve your question-asking skills. If your question has a positive score, it means that the community found it to be a valuable contribution, one which could help others in the future with the same problem.

Downvotes are even more important on questions because they could persuade you to consider editing or even deletion of your post. If your post is disliked by others then you should try to understand if there's anything you could do to improve it. **Ideally, you should do your best to make a perfect question before posting it**, but we all know that we make mistakes, English might not be our native language and Markdown formatting can be intimidating at first.

Of course, no matter how much you try to ask a perfect question **there is no way to correctly predict whether it is going to be successful or not**. I have asked in the past questions which I believed to be very good, but they have been severely downvoted. Asking questions is hard and it is a gamble.

---

In terms of the proposal to hide score from question asker, it would make sense to do so only temporarily. Let the score be easily found if they really want to know, but don't show it prominently to them. The score can be useful, but the emotional fallout resulting from misunderstanding them is not.

Rude and impolite comments under the question demanding written feedback from voters is something that this proposal should aim to avoid. I don't want to see comments in the style of *"Why the downvote?"* or get revenge downvoted because I provided useful comment when downvoting.

If we want to take away one feedback from people (question's score) then we should give something in return. Something that would tell OP that their post is not appreciated here without overtly hurting their feelings or irritating them to the point where they forget about their problem and focus on users.

Comment: The degree of value in that feedback is important. Is it that different from noise?   The proposed concept is: downvotes => asker sees feedback => content edited by asker => trend changed to upvotes/content owner gets answer => overall content quality improved.  To test this, We need to objectively see whether a significant number of questions out of all downvoted questions have improved after a downvote trend. If the number of such  **U** turned questions are high, then "value" of downvote to asker can also be said as high, as  chances are  the question will likely be improved by asker [1/2]

Comment: If on the other hand, most downvoted questions are deleted,  there really isn't any practical advantage to show the votes to the asker. Sure, theoretically, there's a chance op gets his question improved. But if we collectively look at the data, the chances of that happening are low in this case. [2/2]

Comment: I don't like hiding things from people, or make them go out of their way to find out the reality of things.