# Should zero-effort homework dumps and other off-topic questions be flagged as duplicates?

Tags: discussion

Strongly related: [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions)

Sometimes I'll encounter zero-effort homework dumps (or other off-topic questions) that will be flagged as duplicates of existing questions. While the dupe targets often do answer the question, is this basically advising on an off-topic question (since they're giving the OP a link that answers the question)?

That being said, is it "wrong" to flag questions like this as a duplicate?

Here's an example of what I'm referring to:
[image]

Comment: Users wielding a dupe hammer can close close-worthy questions faster this way. Without answers and a negative score, Roomba will take care of these questions, too.

Comment: Often enough duplicates answer the question *if it were a regular question* (solve the problem) but not *if it were a homework question* (solve the exercise). The askers still have to invest *some* effort.

Comment: Off-topic, but looking at the title of the question one can easily find out the names you redacted.

Comment: @JeanneDark so, if users had the same ability to close it as other reasons, those reasons would be better, no?

Comment: There is an industry based on people paying others to do their homework, e.g. through [Fiverr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiverr). Some of those services dump it on Stack Overflow, [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour), etc., often not even changing the format to not look like homework. They must have a sufficient high success rate (otherwise they wouldn't continue doing it).

Comment: So: what's the O(n) algorithm?

Comment: All no-effort questions, homework or not, should be voted down and immediately voted to close.  They are a violation of the "contract" where we help those who are willing to put in the work.  And we shouldn't have to go dupe-hunting for it, it should be CLOSE reason in itself.

Comment: @EricDuminil it's easy to prove there can't be an algorithm faster than O(n^2). With n distinct input elements, there must be `(n * (n - 1)) / 2` distinct pairs in the output.

Comment: @Carl: Indeed. The question seemed pretty specific, though, as if OP knew there existed a better algorithm than O(n²). I've already been surprised by efficient algorithms in the past, I was hoping it would be the case. But you're right, it's a lost cause with distinct input elements.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Do close them as a suitable duplicate**, assuming that *no other close reason* applies.

The main concern with giving advice on off-topic questions is that it does not contribute to the repository in two ways:

1. It makes off-topic content harder to clean up.
2. It does not contribute to teaching the user not to do that again.

But in this case, there is a line between what makes a question *low quality* and *altogether unsuitable for the site*.
By closing as a duplicate, often *quickly* by a gold badge holder, an answer is given to the asker while leaving a potential signpost. That the question shows no effort is a reason to downvote the question, so as to signal that its usefulness is questionable.
And by garnering downvotes, the poster should understand that not enough effort was laid on the question and will prevent them from learning that such behavior is OK. In fact, they will need to take the extra mile of understanding the duplicate, which in itself is a suggestion to lay more effort on a question. And although unlikely, if the question actually ends up being positively received, it's *mission accomplished* anyway.

Closing for another reason would only provide the benefit of potentially triggering the Roomba sooner, but not much else. No answer is given, which frustrates the asker more than giving a duplicate.

In the end, I do not believe that there is a systematic problem with the site regarding questions which should have been closed as a duplicate or closed as another reason, but the former appears to work better towards our goals.

Comment: I could agree on your answer but there is a point that I feel very strongly. People that post _zero-effort homework dumps_ will be rewarded with a duplicate. They will go away satisfied with the outcome of their actions, they will get a good vote from their teachers and will be back again with another _zero-effort homework dumps_. In this specific case I will never give the bones to these lazy dogs.

Comment: @Steve In my experience, most people who post zero-effort homework dumps aren't satisfied with a duplicate because they want an answer that they can just mindlessly copy-paste. If they're willing to put in the effort to learn/adapt a more general solution, they're usually willing to put the effort to ask a decent question in the first place.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery perhaps, but still I don't think that in that particular case there is a gain for the site to help them in that way. I generally downvote and close as _needs details or clarity_

Comment: @Steve using gold hammer shortens the window in which FGITWs might have a chance of answering the question.

Comment: @Steve What John Montgomery and Antti Haapala said resonate with me. They still need to work with the duplicate to solve their own problem, and there are mechanisms in place to stop users from persistently posting poor quality questions. As for FGITWs, delete votes can be employed for very bad (or very common) duplicate questions.

Comment: @Steve, aren't such questions get downvoted and counted towards ban? Rewarded with duplicate, sure, but at cost. Though I agree, such questions should somehow give feedback of how to improve them and by providing the answer chances that following up questions will improve are low.

Comment: It is probably because of my education, but I find this type of questions very irritating. When I started learning programming (80s) I didn't have the luxury of asking about it on StackOverflow. Everything I learned was born from my desire to understand how things worked and from reading books imported from the States and strictly written in English. I still remember wondering if it was safe to send $30 to this Amazon company. Unfortunately the Italian translations were simply incomprehensible.

Comment: And so I can say that the little I have learned has always been thanks to my efforts. I just can't conceive that a person who shows no effort to try to solve their problems should be helped.

Comment: @Steve Pro tip: shift the mindset into assuming that you're not helping the OP, but anyone else who might stumble upon the question while it lives. It was never about the OP, but if that OP posted a question which was indexed, the least we can do is quickly place a sign post for whoever reaches it in the meantime.

Comment: @E_net4thecloserasduplicate that's seems a different and probably healthier mindset.

Comment: @Steve The problem is that you, and I, and most of the users on Meta are of the same mindset, while most of the users on Stack Overflow are not. The massive and continuing rise of programming has led to far more people in that field, and it's unfortunately a statistical certainty that some of those people will be useless leeches for whom effort is an anathema. All we can do is vote to hammer their lazy questions closed whenever we encounter them.

Comment: @Ian Kemp I tend to agree but "most of the users on Stack Overflow" to me implies a majority and I have no idea how to check the mindset of the majority here, even by taking what I read as a sample. If you stick at "many" not "most" I imagine that the wording would match the evidence fairly as well as what you want to say. .

Comment: I thought that questions closed as duplicates would still be subject to the roomba. Isn't that the case?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel They are, but not the same way as questions closed for other reasons. The rules for automatic clean-up end up being mostly the same as for open question, which is why voting is important. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that

Answer (score 17):

> That being said, is it "wrong" to flag questions like this as a duplicate?

If the question is a duplicate, it should be closed as such. The quality of the post doesn't matter to this point. Note that the loss of research effort (although bad) isn't also necessarily a criteria to close a question in the sense of being off-topic.

Sometimes user even [intentionally leave things out to keep a straight and clear focus](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/396963/12139179).

If you find the question shows no research effort where it should have had some (in the case of Homework dumps), use the down-vote button instead.

That's what it is meant for:

[image]

If the question can be answered by another question, it is regardless of all quality aspects a duplicate and it is appropriate to close it as duplicate.

So vote to close such question as duplicate and (if needed - like in this case) show the OP that there was a loss of quality by your down-vote.